# Volley android caching - data is cached even when the max age is 0

Tags: android, caching, android-volley

I used the following statement to fetch the cached data ...

```
mQueue.getCache().get(request.getCacheKey())
```

I noted  that even when max age =0   the above statement was able to fetch the data from the cache . Does the means volley always stores the network response ?But when I tired to  make a  new request data is fetched from network and not cache .So I am confused ...

Answer (score 0):

Data is always cached, but the expiration is checked, and a new request it's made if the request is expired. This way  you can get data from the cache even expired if there's no data connectivity or if you want to show some data while the network request update in the background.